# Rendering Bitmap on SurfaceView impacting performance

Tags: android, bitmap, render, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have an activity which extends SurfaceView  (Android application API level 8). Need to draw bitmap to background instead of simple color. I was able to draw the bitmap on canvas -->using the commented code in void render(Canvas canvas), but it makes to performance too low.

Rendering becomes to slow if we use bitmap, however if we just drawcolor then everything is fine.

Is there issue with the code? How can we set the background image without affecting the performance?

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public void render(Canvas canvas) {


        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        /*
        Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_play);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, null, dest, paint);
        */
        droid.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should create your Bitmap as a field and decode it outside of your render method() like:

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Bitmap myBitmap; //creating a field

    public MainGamePanel() {

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background_play); //decode bitmap in constructor

    }

    public void render(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, null, dest, paint); //draw your bitmap

    droid.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: As well as initializing paint object outside render will improve performance. As dev site says.